# Consumir API com javascript/jquery

Tags: web-service, api

Tenho que consumir uma api em javascript/jquery do IBGE

Click [here](https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/docs/pesquisas?versao=1"),
mas não sei como fazer para que os dados do input preenchido junte com o link
https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/pesquisas/{pesquisas}.
Abaixo o meu código

```
<script>

    var valor1 =  document.getElementById("teste").value;
    $('#botao').click(function() {
    var link ="https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/pesquisas/"+valor1;
    $.ajax({
        url: link,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',

    })
    .done(function() {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(valor1);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = valor1;
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
        console.log("complete");
    });
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Do jeito que você fez, que erro deu?

Comment: Você tentar capturar o codigo com `var valor = $("#idDoCampo").val()` e colocar do jeito que você fez no seu pesquisa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está capturando o valor do campo no momento errado, quando ele ainda não foi preenchido
Desloque a atribuição de `var valor1 = document.getElementById("teste").value;`  para o escopo do evento de click do seu botão.

```
$('#botao').click(function() {
  var valor1 = document.getElementById("teste").value;
  var link = "https://servicodados.ibge.gov.br/api/v1/pesquisas/" + valor1;
  $.ajax({
      url: link,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',

    })
    .done(function() {
      console.log("success");
      console.log(valor1);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = valor1;
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
    .always(function() {
      console.log("complete");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: suaUrlAqui
   success: function(data) {
       // O que pretende fazer aqui.
       //ex:
       var pessoa = JSON.parse(data);
       document.getElementById("CPF").value= pessoa.pessoa[0].CPF;
  }
});
```

Podes pegar a resposta no success e atribuir a uma variável e utilizar essa variável dentro da função do success.